# Create XML file using bcp.exe with proper formatting

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I want to create xml file from query, my goal is to get the format as below

```
<Text>
    <Data>3fgdsg3g</Data>
<Text>
```

In my case I get

```
<Text><Data>3fgdsg3g</Data><Text>
```

All text is on one line, how to make tags on separate lines?
My code

```
BCP.EXE "exec proc_name that return for XML PATH" queryout ...\test.xml -S <servername> -T -w -r
```

Comment: Run the resulting XML file through a "post processor tool" (xmllint, tidy, etc.) that simply formats XML and writes it to a file again.

Comment: The problem is that this is not a one-time action and it needs to be done with sql

Comment: With SQL? How do you execute BCP? From a SQL Job? You could invoke that tool from there too. Also, since technically the non-formatted form is also valid XML, you should probably reconsider the requirements. Why can't you process the non formatted version as well?

Comment: There is probably a problem with the file weight, the files are very large and there is a problem when the data is on one line.

Comment: I dont think this is going to happen. You are going to need another step/action. The data created by your proc is not formatted; it only looks that way when viewed in a result pane; im pretty sure the result viewer is doing the formatting for you, that data itself is not formatted (no inserted tabs, no inserted crlf, etc...). If you want formatting blended into the actual data on the way to your final destination, you're gonna need to add a step for format as Christian K stated. I dont think any of us would want SQL Server to store the formatting with the data.